# Adding all elements of a multi-dimensional array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have an array A, which is x-by-y-by-z-by-w dimensional. I would like to get a z dimensional vector v, where each element of v is the sum of the elements of A controling for the coordinate of v. Is there a way I can do this w/o loops using numpy?

Here is how I would do it with a loop

```
for i in range(z):
   v[i] = np.sum(A[:,:,i,:])
```

Comment: Do you have any code so far?

Comment: I can do it with a loop but was just wondering if there is a more standard way.

Comment: Can you post your `for` loop version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sum over axis by specifying `axis` parameter; Here you want to keep the third axis and *collapse* all the other axises, hence just use `axis=(0,1,3)`:

```
np.sum(A, axis=(0,1,3))
```

---

*Example*:

```
A = np.arange(24).reshape((2,2,3,2))

# for loop approach
z = A.shape[2]
v = np.empty(z)
for i in range(z):
    v[i] = np.sum(A[:,:,i,:])

v
# array([  76.,   92.,  108.])

# sum over axis
np.sum(A, axis=(0,1,3))
# array([ 76,  92, 108])
```